# Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard' from FW 4.8 console app

Tags: .net-4.8, .net-standard-2.0, .net-standard-2.1

I have an older console app that targets .NET Framework 4.8. It loads a few Nugets that all support .NET Standard 2.0 as well as 2.1. The console app builds just fine but I get this runtime error as the first Nuget DLLs gets loaded:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
```

So, compatibility-wise Framework 4.8 should be fine with .NET Standard 2.0. Is there a good reason why the runtime cannot load netstandard 2.0 or 2.1?

[EDIT]
Screenshot from the console app's implicit dependencies
[image]

Comment: How can 2.1 be specifically configured? I only specified the target for the console app (Framework 4.8). Shouldn't MSBuild automatically include the correct binaries from that information, from Nugets with support both netstandard 2.0 and 2.1?

Comment: I edited the OP to include a screenshot from the console app's implicit dependencies. It does include netstandard 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so problem was simply how the project was scaffolded, with assembly unification and upgrade in the `App.config` file. The default was, apparently, to always upgrade netstandard to 2.1, which doesn't work with framework 4.8. Not sure if this is a bug in the Rider project template or if VS also does this. By simply commenting out the assembly upgrade directive the problem got resolved.

[image]

Also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions

[EDIT]: Moving forward, it seems the App.config file gets rewritten every time I change the project setup, like changing project references or adding/removing a Nuget package. I had forgot how messy old framework project really was.

Answer (score 0):

.Netstandard 2.1 requires .NET 5.0+. It is not supported by .NET Framework 4.8. Looks like you are trying to load an assembly that targets netstandard 2.1 only (maybe one of your nugets doesn't support 2.0, or when it has multiple targets, the wrong one is choosen for some reason).

Comment: So, when an executable references Nugets with multi-target support, the compiler/linker can't figure out it needs the correct one (netstandard 2.0 in this case)? Is there anything I can/need to do these days to get it to pick the correct target?

Comment: @JonasRembratt Normally, this works just fine, but maybe something goes wrong in your setup, maybe due to indirect dependencies. Nuget handling in .NET4.8 is still partially broken IIRC. I guess you need to track down which assembly is causing the error (or go forward and change the target runtime to .NET 6.0)

Comment: Looking at the implicit dependency properties, the netstandard binary should be located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\Facades. I checked, and it is. Shouldn't the runtime lib loader (I think it's called 'Fusion') be able to include that location automatically? Maybe some .NET configuration is broken on my box?